# Uniqueness Of Fourier Series.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

The book said:" if $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier Coefficients, then $f$&$g$ are necessarily equal." and it said that"by taking the difference $f - g,$ this proposition can be reformulated as: if $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f = 0.$"

I do not understand how the second statement is a formulation of the first statement? Could anyone explain it for me?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the Fourier series is **linear**. Namely, if $f,g$ are two functions, then the Fourier coefficients of $h\stackrel{\rm def}{=} f-g$ are
$$
\widehat{h}(n) = \widehat{f-g}(n) = \widehat{f}(n)-\widehat{g}(n)
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So the two statements

> (1) For all $h$, $\widehat{h}(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ implies $h=0$.

and

> (2) For all $f,g$, $\widehat{f}(n)=\widehat{g}(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ implies $f=g$.

are equivalent.

The first implies the second by applying (1) to $h\stackrel{\rm def}{=} f-g$; the second implies the first by applying (2) to $f\stackrel{\rm def}{=}h$, $g\stackrel{\rm def}{=}0$.

Comment: .....the Fourier transform is linear or the Fourier Series is linear.

Comment: Actually, both, but I'll correct the phrasing.