# Question about Fourier series of an integral function

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I am asked to calculate the Fourier series of the following integral function:

$$F(t)=\int_0^\pi(\sin(t)+\sin(2t)-\frac{3}{2}\sin(4t))dt$$
Solving the integral it gives me:

$$F(t)=\frac{9}{8}-\cos(t)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t)+\frac{3}{8}\cos(4t)$$
Apparently, this is already the Fourier series of $F(x)$ (textbook's solution).

How can I deduce that?

Comment: Because it is a Fourier series and fourier series are unique

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176139/uniqueness-of-fourier-series) may be of interest to the OP.

Comment: Your integral defining $F(x)$ does not contain $x$.  Did you mean $x$ as the upper limit, not $\pi$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg My bad, I edited the problem

Comment: As written $F=[-cos(t)-\frac{cos(2t)}{2}+\frac{3cos(4t)}{8}]_0^\pi=2$.