Uniqueness of the fourier coefficients
we assume that f is riemann integrable and we say that if f(x) ~ g(x) then g(x) is its fourier series so we could represent the fourier series of f this way:
$f(x) \sim \hat{f}(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \left( \hat{f}(n) + \hat{f}(-n) \right) \cos(nx) + i \left( \hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n) \right) \sin(nx) \right]$
where: $\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} \, dx$
I am asked to show that The given series is not a fourier series of any function:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)}$$
now it really seems like we can get
$\hat{f}(0) = 0$ and $\hat{f}(n) = -\hat{f}(-n)$ for all $n$. For $n=1$, we also have $\hat{f}(1) = \hat{f}(-1)$, and for all $n \geq 2$ we also have $\hat{f}(n) - \hat{f}(-n) = \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$.
This essentially means we are writing $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\ln(n)}$ with its corresponding $\cos(nx)$ term in the sum starting from $n=1$ and adding $\hat{f}(0)$ to be $0$ .
why can I do that? can I know for sure that those are the terms? yes they work but is this representation unique?

Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176139/uniqueness-of-fourier-series Is helpful.

but that is right only if f and g are continuous, what happens when it is just riemann integrable?

In the space of Riemann integrable functions with  $L^2-$norm the Fourier series converges to the function. I just could not find a link in stack exchange to this fact. It is in some books. E.g., Pedersen's book "From calculus to analysis".

how does convergence in L^2 helps me?

two functions with the same Fourier coefficients must then be equal in the $L^2-$norm.  Of course, two functions such that $\int |f-g|=0$ will have the same Fourier coefficients.

What I have here is 2 functions with the same fourier series.  One of them, the first one is written in its standard form with the coefficients in place. the second one, the latter is written, you could say "after some cleaning" and it looks like this cleaning is very specific. but maybe the coefficients somehow cancel each other and I still get the latter series.
